# Using an index range to search ascii

Tags: python, indexing, ascii, indices, caesar-cipher

I am trying to search through the ascii index to write a caesar cipher program with the range being >= 32 and <= 126. When I get to the last print out I get some characters that are not in that range. I have tried for loops and while loops, but keep getting errors.

I apologize if I did not post this properly. It is my first post.

Thanks for any help.

```
    def cipher(phrase,shift):

        x = list(str(phrase))
        xx = ''.join(list(str(phrase)))

        yy = []
        print(x)
        for c in xx:
            yy.append(chr(ord(c)+shift))

        return ''.join(yy)

    print(cipher('ABCDE', 97 - 65))
    print(cipher('abcde', 65 - 97))
    print(cipher(' !\"#$', 95))
```

and my output is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
abcde
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
ABCDE
[' ', '!', '"', '#', '$']
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the lines where you assign `x` and `xx`? I don't think you need those. You can just iterate directly over `phrase`.

Comment: why the shift is 95 for the last print?

Comment: when you run `print(cipher(' !\"#$', 95)) ` you are shifting all of the characters above 126. So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Wyatt x is just for me to print out to see the original against the print out I am looking for. xx was to .join so it wouldn't print out like abcde instead of ['a','b','c','d','e']. I basically just did that, in the beginning, to see if I got it to print out correctly and never removed them.

Comment: @gommb I am shifting 95 because that is the requirement of the assignment. He wants us to loop through ascii index 32 - 126 in the cypher

Comment: @engr_s  I am shifting 95 because that is the requirement of the assignment. He wants us to loop through ascii index 32 - 126 in the cipher. I just can't figure out how to loop through those particular Indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (note that I cleaned your code up a bit):

```
def cipher(phrase, shift):

    x = list(str(phrase))
    yy = ''
    print(x)
    for c in phrase:
        dec = ord(c) + shift
        while dec < 32:
            dec = 127 - (32 - dec)
        while dec > 126:
            dec = 31 + (dec - 126)
        yy += (chr(dec))

    return yy

print(cipher('ABCDE', 97 - 65))
print(cipher('abcde', 65 - 97))
print(cipher(' !\"#$', 95))
```

The output is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
abcde
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
ABCDE
[' ', '!', '"', '#', '$']
 !"#$
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. That code edit worked.

Comment: Isn't this just the same as doing `cipher(' !"#$', 0)` in the original code?

Comment: @Wyatt Yes but i assume it is just a test to make sure it wraps around correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about finding a solution that uses modulo with a range that doesn't start at 0, so here's this:

```
def cipher(phrase, shift):
    """Shift phrase; return original and shifted versions."""
    collector = []
    for c in phrase:
        i = ord(c)
        if i < 32 or i > 126:
            raise ValueError('Char not in range [32, 126]: %s' % c)
        # Shift into range [0, 95)
        i -= 32
        # Apply cipher shift
        i += shift
        # Push the shifted value back into [0, 95) if necessary
        i %= 95
        # Shift back into range [32, 126]
        i += 32
        # Convert to char
        d = chr(i)
        collector.append(d)
    return phrase, ''.join(collector)

print(cipher('ABCDE', 97 - 65))
# -> ('ABCDE', 'abcde')
print(cipher('abcde', 65 - 97))
# -> ('abcde', 'ABCDE')
print(cipher(' !"#$', 95))
# -> (' !"#$', ' !"#$')
```